# ReactJs Integration with the existing code in ExtJs on Eclipse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eclipse, jsx

I am beginner to Full Stack Development and I wanted to ask how can I use React and all the third party dependencies in Eclipse. Actually I already have an application developed on Extjs but now I want to develop a part of the application using React and I have developed the part using it on Vs Code but I am not able to integrate it to my existing code in Eclipse(w/o any plugin) .. as Eclipse dose not support JSX and other things.I would really appreciate if I would get help from someone on this.

Comment: Install [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I appreciate it but I am looking for a solution without using a plugin...

Comment: Eclipse consists of plug-ins and _Eclipse Wild Web Developer_ is part of the _Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers_ IDE package.